# convert xml var to column

Tags: sql-server, xml

I shred XML by  assigning an xml column value to a xml variable and I then do the following:

```
select s.property.value('@name[1]', 'varchar(100)') as name1
       ,s.property.value('@value[1]', 'varchar(100)') as value1

from @s1.nodes('//properties/property') as s(property)
```

where @s1 is the variable.

How can I use this syntax directly against an XML column in a table (2008 R2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cross apply, then select out the values:

```
create table #xmltable (
            x xml
        )

insert #xmltable (x) values ('<xml><properties><property name="name1" value="value1" /><property name="name2" value="value2" /></properties></xml>')


select  p.value('@name', 'varchar(100)') as name,
        p.value('@value', 'varchar(100)') as value
    from #xmltable xt
    cross apply xt.x.nodes('//properties/property') t(p)


drop table #xmltable
```